# Conditionally update dataframe column if character exists in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which consists of two columns, full name and last name. Sometimes, the last name column is not filled properly. In such cases, the last name would be found as the last word in the full name column between parenthesis. I would like to update my last name column for those cases where parenthesis are found to be equal to the word between parenthesis.

Code

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'full':['bob john smith','sam alan (james)','zack joe mac', 'alan (gracie) jacob (arnold)'],
        'last': ['ross', '-', 'mac', '-']
        })
result_to_be = pd.DataFrame({
        'full':['bob john smith','sam alan (james)','zack joe mac', 'alan (gracie) jacob (arnold)'],
        'last': ['ross', 'james', 'mac', 'arnold']
        })
print(df)
print(result_to_be)
```

I have tried to implement the contains function to be used as a mask but it seems to be messing the check regex when checking if it contains ')' or '(' characters

```
df['full'].str.contains(')')
```

The error it shows is

> re.error: unbalanced parenthesis at position 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.str.findall` to get the value between the parentheses and `df.loc` to assign that where `last` is `-`:

```
df.loc[df['last'] == '-', 'last'] = df['full'].str.findall('\((.+?)\)').str[-1]
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                           full    last
0  bob john smith                ross  
1  sam alan (james)              james 
2  zack joe mac                  mac   
3  alan (gracie) jacob (arnold)  arnold
```

Answer (score 1):

For a slightly different syntax, you could also use `extract`

```
df.loc[df['last'] == '-', 'last'] = df['full'].str.extract('.*\((.*)\)', expand=False)
```

Output:

```
                           full    last
0                bob john smith    ross
1              sam alan (james)   james
2                  zack joe mac     mac
3  alan (gracie) jacob (arnold)  arnold
```